# How to get android app versionName from AirWatch APIS

Tags: android, react-native, vmware, airwatch

I want to fetch *versionName* of all app/product deployed to AirWatch, using [Airwatch api's](https://resources.workspaceone.com/view/zv5cgwjrcv972rd6fmml/en)
but I am not sure if any API available for that or not.

I searched in [document](https://resources.workspaceone.com/view/zv5cgwjrcv972rd6fmml/en)  but I am not able to find any api name. Can anyone tell me service name to get versions of android application.

**Edit1:**
Below calls not returning any data. am I missing something

```
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=idTest&id=1520&pageTest=1
https:host/api/mdm/devices/1520/apps?page={page}&pagesize=1
```

This way calling other services and working

```
"https://host/api/mdm/devices?searchby=Serialnumber&id=jjjQA7AL"
```

**Edit2:** When I am using URI

```
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=Serialnumber&id=R10QA7AL&page=1&pagesize=1
```

Getting kind of sample data(not related to my products)

```
{"DeviceApps":[{"ApplicationName":"Amazon Kindle","Version":"8.21.1.0","BuildVersion":"","Status":2,"Size":"122252286","ApplicationIdentifier":"com.amazon.kindle","Type":"System","IsManaged":false}],"Page":1,"PageSize":1,"Total":61}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Functionality**: Retrieves the detail s of the applications that are present on the device.

```
APIURI–https://host/api/mdm/devices/{id}/apps?page={page}&pagesize={pagesize}
```

With the above API, you can get various information about the Apps that are installed on the device. **You can refer to Chapter 6 of the Document specifically page 361-363**

**Edit-1**

example: `https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=Serialnumber&id=R10QA7AL&page=1&pagesize=50`

**Edit-2**

You can use any of the following option in searchby parameter

```
Macaddress,Udid,Serialnumber,ImeiNumber
```

examples:

```
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=Serialnumber&id=R10QA7AL&page=1&pagesize=50
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=ImeiNumber&id=YourID&page=1&pagesize=50
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=Udid&id=YourID&page=1&pagesize=50
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=Macaddress&id=YourID&page=1&pagesize=50
```

**Edit:3** If you want to get all pages or all apps, remove page and pagesize params. like this

```
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=Serialnumber&id=R10QA7AL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it. I can't seen images in my m/c as URL restricted.

Comment: @r15 np, just go to the document as mentioned in the answer :)

Comment: I have tried first api and alternate api but both are not returning any result. Seems I am not calling those in proper way. Can you please check updated question where I am showing how I am calling services. Thank you.

Comment: APIURI you have given could you please format it with dummy values.

Comment: @r15, please check added an example

Comment: When I am using above code service calling successfully but getting kind dummy data(not related to my products). One more option we can have by using `id` (instead  of serialNo) if we use given `APIURI`. I have `id` value can you please give my sample URI of your `APIURI` by using dummy value. Please check edited question. Thank you.

Comment: @r15, I've included all the possible combinations that are possible using searchby parameter

Comment: Thank you so much. You have given example only of alternate api not the main one which using `id` from document. However I am checking these combination first.

Comment: @r15, I used the alternate api because the same pattern worked for you as you've mentioned in Edit-1 and secondly it provides more flexibility

Comment: @r15, question: the json response you posted in your questions says 61 pages, did you check all the 61 Apps information?

Comment: I have checked all pages. This is giving all application installed in my mobile along with versionName(upto here fine. I can filter apps I need or deployed to airwatch server) but the problem is few as are 'failed to install' I need to get version of those apps too to append(suffix) version with app names in product/app list. I am trying to check with other combinations too. I have no idea how page size I should Pass because 61 getting after calling api not before. Thank you.

Comment: @r15, you can try asking a separate question for getting "failed to install" details, as it's kinda separate issue from this one. And try putting all the relevant info their with what you are getting and what you want

Comment: I am facing issue. How can I get all apps. If I pass page 61 I am not getting any apps. If I pass 60 some apps are coming. Out of 61 apps, My apps are 10+. in device. If you have idea Can you please tell me how to solve this issue. What page size should I send. Clients have different devices and mobiles. Thank you.

Comment: @r15 you can try setting pagesize to any arbitrarily large number say 150 to get all the apps in one request.

Comment: When I am exceeding given size result getting 0 records. Can you please have look on page 361 deprecated APIS. Can I use it.

Comment: @r15, usage of deprecated APIs are discouraged always. You need to run pagination with small number of page size say 20. And if it doesn't match your expectation then you might need to contact the support team of VMWare. We've already done what is possible according to documentation.

Comment: Yeah I will check pagination too. I've tried _Serial Number_ deprecated API for just to see result, this way `https://host/api/mdm/devices/serialnumber/R10QA7AL/apps` but not working(returning: 404 not found). Am I setting values correctly? Thank you.

Comment: I have got all app of my device if I remove `page` and `pagesize` params. I couldn't have done w/o your help bro. Thank you.

Comment: @r15, glad you got it working. request you to accept my answer :) so that it may help others in the future.